# ASP.NET MVC View (Razor) Working With Forms Checking Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the standard ASP.NET MVC version installed with Visual Studio.

In thew view I have a companyname `textbox` which is using

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

What I would like to do is grab the text box value and then call a function to save the value to another table.  I also only want this to fire if the value has changed.

I hope that's enough information.

Comment: Can you please post your code, even if it's not working?

Comment: I would but it's just standard code which is generated by the scaffolding.

I have be playing around with the following

Comment: What I meant is, have you tried something in the controller action that didn't work? If yes, please post the code.

Comment: @RamblingGeek: Do you want to fire a function every time text is changed in textbox?

Comment: When you say that you want to "save the value to another table", do you mean an html table in the page or a database table? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Ah Sorry.  Database Table. I have that working. I;m just trying to figure out the following : -
* Grab CompanyName (So I have a copy of it before its changed)
* If the companyname is changed, then write the change back to a DB table names previousCompanyNames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of scenario you're after is best handled in the controller action that handles the POST request when your form gets submitted. For example, assuming you are using Entity Framework to save to the database:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditPost(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var companyToUpdate = db.Companies.Find(id);

    if (TryUpdateModel(companyToUpdate, "",
            new string[] { "Name" }))
    {
        try
        {
            db.Entry(companyToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (SomeException ex)
        {
            //Can also log the error 
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
        }
    }

    return View(companyToUpdate);
}
```

Please note that the POST request can also be sent by javascript.

For more information about this, please have a look at the [asp.net website](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application).

Answer (score 0):

As far as i have understood, you can do something like this:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#CompanyName").change(function(){
      var textValue= $(this).val();

       //Call your function here: YourFunction(textValue);

       $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'ControllerName/ActionMethodName',
       data: {textValue: textValue}, //Keep the same parameter name in C# function
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(result)
       {
         // To do on successful ajax call
       },
       error: function(x,y,z)
       {
         alert("Ajax Error!");
       }
       });

      });
    });
    </script>
```

In C#, you can write something like:

```
public class ControllerNameController : Controller
{  
    public JsonResult ActionMethodName(string textValue)
    {
        // To do your job here
        return Json("succesful", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }   
}
```

You can check it in [jSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bhtukrb5/)

Comment: Great, thanks for that. Sorry Old time windows form programmer trying to get up to speed with MVC Stuff.  So can I call a c# function ?

Comment: @RamblingGeek: Yes, you can make an ajax call to a C# function. Please check my updated answer above. If it solves your problem, you can accept the answer and vote up.